# Изменить имя кнопки в зависимости от нажатия

Tags: php

Вопрос элементарный. Есть кнопка - у нее есть имя (имя меняется в зависимости от нажатия). нужно отловить. Предположим, первоначально value = 1, затем 0, затем снова 1. Ну и таким образом. Данные из кнопки летят в php. Как сделать этот простой переключатель?
объясняю на пальцах. есть кнопка(ну пусть сабмит как у меня)

```
 <td><input type="submit" name="interval" value="<?php echo "$butttn"; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('newFormAdv').submit()" > </td>
```

собственно в пхп 
     $butttn == "Смены"
   т.е. необходимо нажать на кнопку - произойдет изменение с "Смены" на "Сутки", а затем наоборот по повторному нажатию. Я это сделал, но очень коряво. Хочу совет от мастеров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А причем имя к value? Может у Вас значение меняется? Или Имя тоже?
Можете его словить в массиве $_REQUEST. Все что прийдет будет в нем, и имя и значение

Вашу задачу представить сложно!

Comment: в общем нужен пхп. Js НЕ НУЖЕН.

Comment: $butttn = (!isset($_REQUEST['interval'])||$_REQUEST['interval']!='Смены') ? 'Смены' : 'Сутки';

Пробуй

Answer (score 1):

Что значит каким образом летят? Для этого либо пользуются отправкой формы либо пользуются аякс отправкой формы по событию change у флажка(кнопки).